# What are the advantages of using SingletonBeanFactoryLocator to initiate a singleton bean

Tags: spring, singleton

I'm new to Spring Framework, What are the advantages of using SingletonBeanFactoryLocator to initiate a singleton bean, is there any alternatives for SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use that, use dependency injection instead.

Comment: But I'm calling the Application context from a jar in order to load the beans inside the jar file, so i don't think that i can use Dependency Injection at this scenario.

Comment: And why not? Just add the xml file from inside the jar as an `<import resource />` to your own configuration (or use `@ImportResource`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. let me try this.